# Internationalization in javascript not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, unicode, character-encoding

I am working on internationalization of my web project, I am able to display kannada words in html using unicode but I can't do the same for javascript alert.

[image]

Comment: We are in 2017. Just use UTF-8.

Comment: @Alvaro i did that before posting this question and the output was question mark, all the characters got replaced by question mark and the same thing was displayed in javascript alert messages too

Comment: Then you need to do some basic debug. Is your editor configured to save files as UTF-8? Is the browser receiving some other encoding in the `Content-Type` header? Is the rest of your application using UTF-8?